# Cakephp 2.8 pulling data from three tables with one common column per pair table

Tags: cakephp

I have three tables, and I want know what is the right Find command to pull the right car models based the category chosen.

```
Category table
---------------------
Cat_ID Category
1      Sedan
2      SUV
3      Truck

Manufacturers tables
--------------------------
CAR_ID  Cat_ID   Manufacturer
1        1          BMW
2        1          BMW
3        2         Mercedes
4        3          Dodge

Model table
--------------
CAR_ID   Model
1        i320
2        i540
3        GL320
4        RAM
```

I was able to pull the right cars based on manufacturers, but it is not working when I try to pull the cars based on the category.

```
$catid='Sedan';

$car_id = $this->car->find('all',array('fields' => array('car.id'),'conditions' => array('car.category_id' => $catid),'order' => array('car.id' => 'desc')));

$models = $this->Model->find('all',array('conditions' => array('Model.car_id'=>$car_id),'order' => array('Model.id' => 'desc')));
```

I want the output to show for the if I pick Sedan, both BMW models i32 and i520.

Comment: CakePHP version 2.x or 3.x ?

Comment: Cake php version 2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join statement

I don't know what version of cakephp you are using but i am using cakephp 2.0.

```
        $this->Model->find('all',[
        'joins' => [
            [
                'table' => 'Manufacturers',
                'alias' => 'Manufacturers',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => [
                    'Category.Cat_ID = Manufacturers.Cat_ID'
                ]
            ],
            [
                'table' => 'Model',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => [
                    'Model.CAR_ID = Manufacturers.CAR_ID'
                ]
            ]
        ]
      ]);
```

if you want to restrict what category you will use then use conditions like below

```
    $this->Model->find('all',[
        'joins' => [
            [
                'table' => 'Manufacturers',
                'alias' => 'Manufacturers',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => [
                    'Category.Cat_ID = Manufacturers.Cat_ID'
                ]
            ],
            [
                'table' => 'Model',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => [
                    'Model.CAR_ID = Manufacturers.CAR_ID'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'conditions' => [
            'Category.Cat_ID' => 1
        ]
    ]);
```

Side note : Using '[]' and array() are technically the same but nevertheless, here is the sample code using array().

```
    $this->Category->find('all', 
    array(
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'Manufacturers',
                'alias' => 'Manufacturers',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Category.Cat_ID = Manufacturers.Cat_ID'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'Model',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Model.CAR_ID = Manufacturers.CAR_ID'
                )
            ),
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Category.Cat_ID' => 1
        )
    ));
```

Update 2

```
        $this->Model->find('all', 
        array(
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'Manufacturers',
                    'alias' => 'Manufacturers',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Model.Car_ID = Manufacturers.Car_ID '
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'table' => 'Category',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Category.Cat_ID= Manufacturers.Cat_ID'
                    )
                ),
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Category.Cat_ID'=>$cat_id
            )
        ));
```

Comment: Thank you Albert. I think you are missing the array (), can you add the array into your answer.

Comment: basically array() and [] are technically the same. You can use either when programming in cakephp. Anyways, I've updated my answer to cater to your question :D

Comment: Thank you Albert, I am still a beginner in cakephp.  I need the output to be Model matched records, what I am getting is the whole category table. can you verify your code my friend.

Comment: Just replace the 'type' => 'LEFT', with 'type' => 'INNER',

Comment: Still the same problem, When I do dump_var I get the categories table matching the category Sedan many times.

Comment: Albert, I am sure it should be $this->Model->find('all', ....), but when I do that, I get Category.Cat_ID column not found error.

Comment: Abert, it worked, but you need to change the last line to category.id=$cat_id

Comment: Albert, you have been AMAZING! Thank you!

Comment: No prob :) glad to help